# Determine retention period set on Azure Log Analytics workspace

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

Is there a way to determine the data retention period set on an existing Log Analytics workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the details of retention in [pricing details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/monitor/)

[image]

> The first 5 GB of data ingested to the Azure Log Analytics service
>   every month is offered free.
>
> Every GB of data ingested into your Azure Log Analytics workspace is
>   retained at no charge for the first 31 days.

Comment: I was referring to what the configured retention period is for an existing workspace.